# R staticdocs, titles of demos

Tags: r

Does anyone know, using R staticdocs, how to define the name of the demos? The title in the html file that is produced is not reflective of what is contained within the demo 00Index file?

Comment: `demo(package = "staticdocs")` informs you about demo_name. Then you run `demo(demo_name, package = "staticdocs") `

Comment: No I am talking about generating staticdocs documentation, via this: https://github.com/hadley/staticdocs The demo page titles (ie within <h1>Some Title</h1>) for the demo files, is not as per the titles listed in the 00Index file.

Comment: I completely made a mistake. Sorry, I couldn't help you.

Comment: @cuttlefish44 no problems, I worked it out and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Think there is something missing in the demo building routine, the following is a sligtly modified routine from that which comes standard with staticdocs. Basically, the pgk$title attribute should be set, which I have tried to highlight below:

```
build_demos = function (pkg = ".") {
      pkg <- staticdocs::as.sd_package(pkg)
      demo_dir <- file.path(pkg$path, "demo")
      if (!file.exists(demo_dir)) 
        return()
      message("Rendering demos")
      demos <- readLines(file.path(demo_dir, "00Index"))
      pieces <- stringr::str_split_fixed(demos, "\\s+", 2)
      in_path <- stringr::str_c(pieces[, 1], ".r")
      filename <- stringr::str_c("demo-", pieces[, 1], ".html")
      title <- pieces[, 2]
      for (i in seq_along(title)) {
        demo_code <- readLines(file.path(demo_dir, in_path[i]))
        demo_expr <- evaluate::evaluate(demo_code, new.env(parent = globalenv()), new_device = FALSE)

        #NH: replay_html is not exported...
        replay_html <- getFromNamespace('replay_html','staticdocs')

        pkg$demo      <- replay_html(demo_expr, pkg = pkg, name = stringr::str_c(pieces[i],"-"))
        pkg$pagetitle <- title[i]

        #---------------------------------------------------
        #NH: Need to set the title attribute...
        #---------------------------------------------------
        pkg$title     <- pkg$pagetitle
        #---------------------------------------------------

        staticdocs::render_page(pkg, "demo", pkg, file.path(pkg$site_path, filename[i]))
      }
      invisible(list(demo = unname(apply(cbind(filename,title), 1, as.list))))
    }
```